# How to find ID for existing Fi-Ware sensors

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm working with Fi-Ware and I would like to include existing information from smartcities on my project. Clicking on the link below I could find information about how is the ID pattern and type of different device (for example OUTSMART.NODE.).

https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Sample_code

However, I don't know the  after that pattern 
I've tried random numbers (OUTSMART.NODE.1 or OUTSMART.NODE.0001).

Is there some kind of list or somewhere to find that information??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know the particular entity IDs for a given type, you can use a "discovery" query on the type associated to the sensor with the `.*` global pattern. E.g., in order to get the IDs associated to type "santander:traffic" you could use:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "santander:traffic",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "attributes" : [
       "TimeInstant"
    ]
}
```

Using "TimeInstant" in the "attributes" field is not strictly needed. You can leave "attribute" empty, in order to get all the attributes from each sensor. However, if you are insterested only in the IDs, "TimeInstant" would suffice and you will save length in the JSON response (the respone of the above query is around 17KB, while if you use an empty "attributes" field, the response will be around 48KB).

**EDIT:** since the update to Orion 0.14.0 in orion.lab.fi-ware.org on July 2nd, 2014 the NGSI API implements pagiation. The default limit is 20 entities so if you want to get all them, you will need to implement pagination in your cliente, using limit and details URI parameters. Have a look to the [pagination section in the user manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Pagination) for details.