# Discovering devices in Orion

Tags: curl, command, fiware-orion, fiware

I'm new in Fi-Ware and I'm trying to do something useful with it.
In particular, I've found some of the commands to get some information, but you know that when you ask you need the ID of the device. I haven't found a clear command, with curl, to get the list of the ID in SmartSantander.

Can anyone tell me if he/she could, and what command it is?
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think It will depend on how the EntityIds are modeled in that scenario.

The idea could be to use the query context command returning all the Entities matching a given regexp pattern (functionality available just in the ID field). Ideally the EntityId must be namespaced enough to make posible this kind of query requests.

Take into account the "attributeList" param, if you don't want to retrieve all the information from the whole response set.

More info:

https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Query_Context_operation

Comment: Perrolobo, entityIds have this format:    ],
        "id": "urn:smartsantander:testbed:357",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "type": ""
    }, So I've tried to ask the info by "urn:smartsantander:testbed:3.*" as I've seen in your url. I get an error response when I do. My complete command is this "curl orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/urn:smartsantander:testbed:3.* -X GET -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header "X-Auth-Token: xxxx" | python -mjson.tool"

Comment: It seems that you are using convenience /REST/ operations to do so. I would recommend to use a variation of the example provided in the documentation, that is POSTing a Json with the regexp and "isPattern" set to TRUE: `(curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
    {
        "type": "Room",
        "isPattern": "true",
        "id": "Room.*"
    }
    ],
    "attributes" : [
    "temperature"
    ]
}
EOF`

Comment: Ok @Perrolobo, I've tried that command. This time I get this message "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1026: Connection refused" I've seen in another post that this may happen if you don't run Orion. I didn't need to run it with the other command. I'm using ubuntu and there must be some problem with the packages because I can't run Orion

Comment: I'm not giving you the exact example for your use case. You will need to adapt it. Try use your target Orion instance (orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/) instead of local host, and of course adapt the JSON to the smartSantander domain.

Comment: Appart from adapting the hostname to orion.lab.fi-ware.org (as @Perrolobo rightly suggest), you need to use the right entity id and type (e.g. `urn:smartsantander:testbed:3.*`) and attributes. Next, the X-Auth-Token header must be present (otherwise, orion.lab.fi-ware.org will reject your request). You have quick start info in this page, that may be uselful: https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers. Anyway, I will try to provide more comprehensive information on this in a separate answer.

Comment: The link in the above comment is broken and I cannot edit it, sorry. Thus, I will post here again: http://tinyurl.com/orion-quickstart

Answer (score 1):

The list of the different entities types at orion.lab.fi-ware.org can be found in the table in [this section of the Orion Context Broker manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#FI-LAB_context_management_platform). In that table, you can see the different entity types you have available (e.g. santander:lux , santander:traffic, etc.).

Next, in order to know all the IDs belonging to a given type, please have a look to [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990635/how-to-find-id-for-existing-fi-ware-sensors). Pay special attention to the remark about pagination (by default, you will get a maximun of 20 entities).

Finally, once you know the IDs, you can retrieve them either using patterns (as described in other answer to this question) or direcctly for the ID.

Answer (score 1):

By what I gather from the comments in other answers, it looks like you are trying to use convenience operations to get a list of entities by ID and using regular expressions.

This is simply not supported (according to [this](http://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Convenience_Query_Context)):

> It is not possible to use convenience operations to query for lists of entities, entity patterns nor lists of attributes.

You must either:

- Use convenience operations, but query by type to get a list of entities, or by ID to get individual entities.
- Use standard operations, which allow you to use regexps in the ID field (such as suggested by Perrolobo).